# Max zoom are different on a different regions

Tags: leaflet, http-status-code-404

On a land I can zoom up to 20 points, but on the sea/ocean I can only zoom up to 7-12 point (it depends which location you are zooming). If I zoom above 7-12 point on the ocean I see 404 errors in browser console (https://khms0.googleapis.com/kh?v=944&hl=en-GB&x=260660&y=177418&z=19) and when I reach 19 map becomes gray.

Is there a way to limit max zoom value depending on the coordinates you are standing and get rid of console errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `MaxZoomService` [available in the api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom#MaxZoom) to get the max zoom level api available in a certain area.

This way you can follow this algorithm:

1. Get current position
2. Fetch the max zoom available in the current position through the google maps api
3. Set it as the max zoom on leaflet
4. Get the current zoom in in the map
5. If currentZoom > maxZoom, then zoom out to the max zoom available

Answer (score 0):

here is full code:

```
var maxZoomService = new google.maps.MaxZoomService();

map.on('moveend', function () {
  maxZoomService.getMaxZoomAtLatLng(
    map.getCenter(),
    result => {
      if (result.status === "OK") {
        map.options.maxZoom = result.zoom;
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out -- could you explain what's happening your answer so that it stands alone?